# Java Generics and C++ templates, which to be preferred if generated code size matters?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

If we have to choose to implement a solution either using C++ templates or Java Generics and ignoring the remaining languages issues (like the execution time), **which of the them is to be preferred if size of generated code matters**?

I read that in Java Generics the type parameter are thrown after the compilation and not stored in metadata, does this lead to smaller programs or not?

Comment: I fail to see why this question is downvoted or considered 'not constructive'. It asks a factual question which can be answered by empirical measurement, as well as by analysis from first principles. +1

Comment: the problem with this questions is that different compilers may do the job of optimizing differently. So i'm not sure if it can be answered satisfactorily

Comment: From the question it is not even clear what "size" means here - size of generated code? Objects' size im memory? Required team size?

Comment: @GyroGearless size of generated code

Comment: @GyroGearless (NB should be 'Gearloose') Your objection doesn't hold water. What *else* the question could possibly be about other than code size? Object size  isn't affected by code generation techniques as between Generics and templates. In any case why does it matter which of these the OP is asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to understand that these things are not similar. They are in fact almost polar opposites:

- C++ templates generate new types, via code generation at compile time and link time.
- Java Generics restrict existing types, via type algebra at compile time.

From those two facts everything follows. Java Generics add zero cost in space or time; C++ templates add both costs. Adroit inlining and use of non-templated base classes (the old `void *` trick) can minimize the C++ space cost, possibly even eliminate it, but it takes a lot of care, and anticipation of how your C++ compiler actually does inlining.

Comment: How does inlining reduce space cost? On the contrary, it would increase it.

Comment: It puts more of the code into the current compilatiopn unit, where the compiler can better optimize it away, e.g. via tail call optimization.